Which species is this short-bodied cellar spider?
It clearly belongs to the Pholcidae family and possibily the Pholcus genus, but I can't find a picture of any similar spider on the Internet.
Note that the legs of the spider in the picture are curved inside because it is dead (drowned)

(2 spider photo released under CC0 waiver)


Spider in the photo:
status: dead
age: mature
sex: likely male
location: Red River Delta, Vietnam

Creates messy and non-adhesive webs.
Abdomen vibrates when it senses danger.

EDIT: likely a male, the female's abdomen are darker and bigger

Sorry to hear the news; I once had a "pet spider" in a corer of my apartment as well. Could you add some information on the size? There's nothing in the photo that gives a clue. Is the body 1 cm long? More? Less?  Thanks, and Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Sadly i lost the spider body 2 days after taking the picture (before posting this), but the distance between to blue lines in the paper are ~3/4cm

edit previous: not ~3/4cm but ~3/4 of 1cm

This is indeed in the Family Pholcidae but you are unfortunately incorrect in thinking this is of the genus Pholcus
This appears to be a Short-bodied Cellar Spider (Physocyclus globosus) of the genus Physocyclus

Physocyclus globosus, sometimes known as the short-bodied cellar spider is a species of spider belonging to the family Pholcidae. This is a cosmopolitan species, found in caves and buildings throughout the warmer parts of the world. This is a small brown spider (body length around 6 mm), with a short, broad abdomen. A black line runs along the back of the carapace, continuing along most of the abdomen. The eight eyes are grouped close together on a raised hump on the face. Source: wikipedia.org



Image ref: inaturalist.org, Photo 26739006, (c) matthewkwan, some rights reserved (CC BY-ND), uploaded by matthewkwan

That specie have abdomen a bit too big compared to the cephalothorax, but the raised hump eyes are very interesting, i will upload a sideview photo

The photo on Wikipedia show the eyes pair and the abdomen pattern very similar, i think you are correct

@Stvkimension Thank you!
